# How can I write into text file for android application?

Tags: android

I want to write some information about users to reuse them but I cannot create a text file so I cannot read it, too. Before starting to read, I want to accomplish writing to text file.

I wrote the user permission into manifest file.

Also, my code for writing into text file as in below:

```
public static void writeFile(String item, String fileName) throws IOException {

     BufferedWriter out;         
     try {

     FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+fileName);

     out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

     out.write(item);

     out.close(); 

     }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

So can anyone say the problem? Thank you.

Comment: what is wrong with it? what is item (as in what is passed)?

Comment: Actually I don't get any error. Item means what I want to write into file.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, you may want to use sharedpreferences, take a look: [Simple Example Sharedpreferences](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

You can store and retrieve data easily...

Anyway...

Make sure your manifest contains:
1. android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2. android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
    String string1 = "Hey you";

    FileOutputStream fos ;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/filename.txt", true);

        FileWriter fWriter;

        try {
            fWriter = new FileWriter(fos.getFD());
            fWriter.write("hi");
            fWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fos.getFD().sync();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think it to use but how about for multiple users' data?

Comment: sharedPreferences.putString("username1", "joana");

Comment: sharedPreferences.putString("username2", "Ana");

Comment: sharedPreferences.putString("Address1", "joana_Address");

Comment: I know but this can't handle my problem because I want to use these information for autocompletetext.